# What exactly is metadata? How is metadata different than regular data?

Tags: database-design, metadata

As I understand, metadata is data about data- so I think of analytics; is my simple definition correct? How is metadata different than data?  I'm simply asking to broaden my understanding-thanks!

Comment: In the context of a database it can blur.   Column size is meta data to the database.   Lets say you store file name, file location, and file size in the database.  File size to the file is meta data but if you store that in the database then to the database it is regular data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metadata is data that describes your data.  For example "Kenneth" is my name.  It would be stored in a column called FirstName (for example).  The metadata would be things like

- Variable length string with a max length of 50
- First name of the user
- Last updated on
- Last updated by

Analytics is more

- How many Kenneth's are there in the data.
- What is the average number of questions by someone with the first name of Kenneth.

Comment: is metadata essentially column/attribute data-type?

Comment: That's just part of the metadata.  For example date modified could also be called metadata.  As could a comment "This is the users first name" or who last entered the data.  Metadata is any data that describes other data.

Comment: The colloquial usage of "metadata" sometimes implies more than the actual technical definition; I suppose any term/definition is subject to misinterpretation or perversion-thank you.